# How can I start a cronjob 1 hour later each day?

Tags: cron

I need to start a cronjob every day, but an hour later each day. What I have so far works for the most part, except for 1 day of the year:

```
0 0 * * * sleep $((3600 * (10#$(date +\%j) \% 24))) && /usr/local/bin/myprog
```

When the day of year is 365 the job will start at 5:00, but the next day (not counting a leap year) will have a day of year as 1, so the job will start at 1:00. How can I get rid of this corner case?

Comment: Any reason to not just start it every 25 hours?

Comment: And how exactly would you do that? */25 in the hour position will not solve it.

Comment: @HalosGhost Thanks for your suggestion! I wrote a simple implementation based on at.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My preferred solution would be to start the job every hour but have the script itself check whether it's time to run or not and exit without doing anything 24 times out of 25.

crontab:

```
0 * * * *    /usr/local/bin/myprog
```

at the top of `myprog`:

```
[ 0 -eq $(( $(date +%s) / 3600 % 25 )) ] || exit 0
```

If you don't want to make any changes to the script itself, you can also put the "time to run" check in the crontab entry but it makes for a long unsightly line:

```
0 * * * *    [ 0 -eq $(( $(date +\%s) / 3600 \% 25 )) ] && /usr/local/bin/myprog
```

Comment: '%'s need to be escaped with a backslash in the crontab.

Comment: @birch I never knew that! I guess I never before tried to include a % in a crontab. Thanks for the correction, I have edited the answer.

Comment: This looks good to me.  I have no idea what the OP wants to do with respect to Daylight Savings Time (spring ahead, fall behind), but the OP should make adjustments accordingly.

Comment: I'd be slightly worried about rounding in the division. If for some reason the time that `date` got back from the kernel was `1ms` before the time you expected the script to run, the check would give an incorrect result.

Comment: @kasperd I thought about that, but I reasoned that cron will never start the job before the appointed time, always on time or slightly after (in practice, always slightly after, because cron's computations take some small amount of time).

Comment: @Celada At some point I heard about an issue where different CPUs on a multi CPU system could report slightly different time. It could also be that `ntpd` had to adjust the clock backwards because it had drifted. One could also imagine quirks in how `cron` computes how long to sleep between each invocation, though a too late invocation seem like a more likely outcome.

Comment: @kasperd I don't know, I suppose you might be right about different CPUs reporting different time. As for `ntpd`, it does try hard to only slew the clock, not jump it, specifically to avoid this kind of problem, but you're right, it (or `ntpdate`) sometimes can jump the time backwards. As for `cron` miscalculating its sleep delay, I'm pretty sure that would be considered a bug! Still, point taken, and a workaround would be to schedule the job 30 minutes past the hour which is less likely to cause the problem... Or add ±1800 in the arithmetic expression before taking the reamainder mod 3600.

Answer (score 8):

If your system has systemd, you can use timers events for this. Just define a [new service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Writing_custom_.service_files), which should contain the command/task you want to execute, and then create a timer event with the `OnUnitActiveSec` option:

```
[Unit]
Description=daily + 1 hour task

[Timer]
OnUnitActiveSec=25h # run 25 hours after service was last started
AccuracySec=10min

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Use the same name for the files, except that instead of `.service` you use `.timer`.

Synthesizing:

1. Create a file called `job.service` in the `/etc/systemd/system/` directory.
2. [Fill it with the necessary information.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Writing_custom_.service_files) You can verify the configuration, using `systemctl status job.service`.
3. Create a file called `job.timer` in `/etc/systemd/system/`.
4. Fill it with the required information:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=daily + 1 hour task

   [Timer]
   OnUnitActiveSec=25h # run 25 hours after service was last started
   AccuracySec=10min

   [Install]
   WantedBy=timers.target
   ```
5. Verify the timer using `systemctl list-timers`
6. Done.

Comment: If I was going to stray from the simplicity of cron, I'd use launchd, which would require less work than your example for systemd.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind using something other than cronjobs, I would suggest the lesser-known utility `at` . Simply write a wrapper script that both schedules itself to be run in 25 hours, and then calls your program. This seems to be the cleanest solution.
For example, you could write this in ~/script.sh:

```
echo "bash ~/script.sh" | at now + 25 hours
/usr/bin/yourprogram
```

And then simply run `bash ~/script.sh` once.

*Thanks to @HalosGhost for the idea of scheduling the job once in 25 hours.*

Comment: There are 2 problems with using `at` for this purpose: (1) if the job fails to execute correctly even once, it also probably fails to reschedule itself and then not just the next execution but all future executions are effectively cancelled until a human notices, and (2) since the job takes some non-zero time to run, using the naive `now + 25 hours` means it will run a few seconds (or more) later each time, anf this lag will build up over time, making it eventualy run at completely the wrong time.

Comment: You are correct about #1; I'm not so sure about #2. Although I don't have any data, I don't think the delay between the clock changing and the at job being triggered and subsequently rescheduled is large enough to be noticeable - especially considering that the resolution of `at` is limited to minutes and starts all jobs at [time]:00.

Comment: @Celada: Scheduling the next `at` job *first thing* in the at script avoids those problems. Notwithstanding, *if* an error occurs then the whole chain is broken, which may or may not be desired: if the use case is "only run this when it works", not restarting is a great feature. But if the use case is "always run, even if the last failed" then `at` is not the right tool.